# How to replace row in one data frame with matching rows from another dataframe for all columns

Tags: r

I would like to replace a full row of data in one dataframe with matching rows from another dataframe. I have a reproducible example with only a couple of columns, but in practice I have a dataframe with dozens of columns.

```r
# main dataframe
df1 <- tibble(id = letters[1:5], v1 = seq(1,5), v2 = seq(1,5), v3 = seq(1,5))
```

```r
>df1
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  id       v1    v2    v3
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 a         1     1     1
2 b         2     2     2
3 c         3     3     3
4 d         4     4     4
5 e         5     5     5
```

```r
# values to replace
df2 <- tibble(id = letters[3:4], v1 = rep(0,2), v2 = rep(0,2), v3 = rep(0,2))
```

```r
> df2
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  id       v1    v2    v3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 c         0     0     0
2 d         0     0     0
```

```r
# what the final result should look like
result <- tibble(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), v1 = c(1, 2, 0, 0, 5), v2 = c(1, 2, 0, 0, 5), v3 = c(1, 2, 0, 0, 5))
```

```r
>result
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  id       v1    v2    v3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1     1     1
2 b         2     2     2
3 c         0     0     0
4 d         0     0     0
5 e         5     5     5
```

Comment: `df1[match(df2$id, df1$id),] <- df2`

Comment: Using dplyr
`df2 %>% bind_rows(df1) %>% distinct(id, .keep_all = T) %>% arrange(id)`

Comment: @H1 Those this may work on the example I provided I get an error. `Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, match(df2$id, df1$id), , value = list( : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames` Seems like missing values could break this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, if you have ids that exist in df2 but not in df1 you can do:

```
df1[na.omit(match(df2$id, df1$id)),] <- df2[df2$id %in% df1$id,]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  #Stay with the rows that are not found in df2 according to its id
  filter(! id %in% df2$id) %>%
  #bind rows of df2
  bind_rows(df2) %>%
  #Order data according to id values
  arrange(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward solution

```
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "id", suffix = c("", ".x"))
df3[!is.na(df3$v1.x), 2:4] <- df3[!is.na(df3$v1.x), 5:7]
df3[, 5:7] <- NULL
```